# Is this DIY high voltage AC generator safe to use?

Tags: high-voltage

[image]

Making a DIY type high voltage AC power supply from 40 W soldering iron, 220 V AC to 12 or 6 V AC step down transformer and 5 A fuse.
These things are ALL connected in series to the 220 V AC mains.

Am I doing this *"high voltage AC generator"* circuit right?

I am making a high voltage alternating current power supply of 10 - 15 kV enough to generate strong electrostatic influence on deionized water to construct a water bridge and investigate its physical properties for a research.

The circuit consists of a 40 W soldering iron (used as dummy load or sacrificial load in case the transformer fails), 5 A Fuse, and finally a step-down transformer of 220 VAC to 12 VAC or 6 VAC with center tap all connected in series to the AC mains 220 VAC

BTW I am at a beginner level when it comes to controlling high voltages.

Comment: You should include a **schematic** as it is unclear how everything is connected. Sure you can describe it in text but that still does not show all the details. *btw I am at a beginner level when it comes to controlling high voltages* OK, so what could possibly go wrong then eh? Living on the edge.

Comment: wait ill upload it

Comment: https://imgur.com/mBEJQnQ

Comment: No, not good enough, include the picture or draw it yourself using the schematic entry tool. Use **Edit** to update the question.

Comment: Your question has so many wrong ideas that I would strongly suggest you do not start unless you have studied electricity and electronics a lot more: "step down in combination with 10-15kV high voltage". "Soldering iron as dummy load", a "step-down transformer of 220 V AC to 12 V AC or 6 V AC with center tap all connected in series"

Comment: There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar. Use that to upload an image inline with your post. For schematics you can use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click to edit component properties. 'R' to rotate, 'V' and 'H' to flip horizontally and vertically.

Comment: That 230 to 12 VAC transformer you found, you will saturate the transformer and effectivly short it. Also, if you don't know what you are doing, you need to stary far away from mains and/or high voltage!

Comment: You will **not** get 10 - 15 kV from this, you will not. **If** the transformer would get 220 V AC as input (which it will not as the required current would be too high and the transformer would melt) you'd theoretically get 4 KV. But you will not because this will not work like that. High voltage is better left to the **professionals**.

Comment: General rule: if you have to ask the question "is this safe?" the answer is no.

Comment: A step down transformer from 10 to 15 kV down to 220 V may be reversed. Primary (low voltage) winding will be designed and build to be connected to 220 V, secondary (high voltage) winding to deliver the kilovolts. The number of windings and their isolation are designed to be used with that voltages.

Comment: I worked at a company that manufactured 15kV step-up transformers, they were about the size of a house brick, not because of the power they were transforming, but mostly as a result of the carefully designed HV windings, which were either in multiple segments in separate bobbins, or layered carefully with  a lot of interlayer insulation. You won't get a standard 220V transformer to do this without failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you think that the only thing that matters on a transformer specification is the transformer ratio, 240V:12V in this case and that you can apply 220 V to the 12 V winding. This is not the case.

The coil voltage rating is related to the magnetic flux in the core. The 12 V rating is that voltage which will not saturate the core. Exceeding that voltage will cause the core to saturate, the inductance of the coil to drop very low and if the fuse doesn't blow, the current will increase to a level that will burn out the transformer and possibly start a fire.

Even if you didn't have problems on the primary you would have problems on the secondary. The insulation is rated for 220 V operation but you are hoping for several kV. If you were able to generate these voltages the insulation would break down causing shorts on the secondary which would appear as a short on the primary due to transformer action. This again would lead to rapid overheating and possible fire.

As others have advised, stop now.

Comment: *As others have advised, stop now.* That is good advise and you will have lost nothing as this setup would not have worked anyway.

Comment: Note that the fuse won't blow because the dummy load will limit the current. That is the point of using such a dummy load.